# php multidimension array sum calculation

Tags: php

I have an multidimension array with 16 values in each array,i want to use a formula to convert each value in the array 
for example

```
$res_arr= array(
    0=>array(1,2,3,6,7,8,9,11,33,44,55,66,77,88,16,18),
    1=>array(17,52,38,666,79,8,9,15,33,44,55,66,76,88,16,18),
    2=>array(17,562,538,7666,579,688,9,15,933,44,55,660,76,808,106,108),
);
```

After converting i need to calculate sum of corresponding key element
for example after conversion i get an array like

```
$avArray=array(
    0=>array(.1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7....,.16),
    1=>array(.11,.21,.33,.44,.55,.66,.77....,.16),
    2=>array(.21,.21,.33,.43,.6,.67,.877....,.16)
)
i should be able to calculate 
.1+.11+.21,.2+.21+.21,.....
```

Below is the code i used ,with this i get blank value.

```
<?
$avArray = array();
foreach ($res_arr as $k=>$subArray)
    {

        $avArray[$k] += pow(10,round(($subArray-100.0/10),2))* 5/12;



    }
<table><tr>
for($i=0; $i<=16;$i++)
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($num);
            echo "<td>". print_r($avArray) ."</td>";


    }
</tr></table>
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure your `$avArray` looks like the example you posted? Your conversions code below wouldn't produce that `$avArray`

Comment: $avArray is just an example

Comment: Please mark the best answer as accepted in order to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this. Change that part of code(between foreach) to this:

```
foreach ($res_arr as $k=>$subArray)
    {
        $avArray[$k]=0;
        foreach($subArray as $value)
            $avArray[$k] += pow(10,round(($value-100.0/10),2))* 5/12;
    }
```

Comment: i think it should also have the pow(10,round(($value-100.0/10),2))* 5/12/count(res_arr ) ?;

Comment: Maybe. But you didn't mention that in your example. There is only a sum statement.

Comment: And also I think you meant count($subArray).

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is what you want: http://codepad.org/ivL5vVKf

```
$res_arr = 
array(
    0=>array(1,2,3,6,7,8,9,11,33,44,55,66,77,88,16,18),
    1=>array(17,52,38,666,79,8,9,15,33,44,55,66,76,88,16,18),
    2=>array(17,562,538,7666,579,688,9,15,933,44,55,660,76,808,106,108),
);

$avArray = array(
    array(),
    array(),
    array(),
);

foreach ($res_arr as $k=>$subArray)
{
    foreach($subArray as $val)
    {
        $avArray[$k][] = pow(10,round(($val-100.0/10),2))* 5/12;
    }
}

$results = array();

for( $i = 0; $i < count($avArray[0]); $i++ )
{
    $results[$i] = $avArray[0][$i] + $avArray[1][$i] + $avArray[2][$i];
}

print_r($results);
```

the `$results` array contains the sums of the other values... for example `$results[0]` is equal to `$avArray[0][0] + $avArray[1][0] + $avArray[2][0]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alterative version with [`PHP's array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) combined with [`array_sum()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php).

```
$avArray = array();
foreach( $res_arr as $k => $v ) {
    $avArray[$k] = array_sum( array_map(function( $n ){ 
        return pow( 10, round(( $n - 100.0 / 10 ), 2 )) * 5/12;
    }, $v ));
}

/**
 * print_r( $avArray ); prints
**/
array
(
    [0] => 4.16666666671E+77
    [1] => INF
    [2] => INF
)
```

`array_sum()` sums the `array()` applied after `array_map()` has iterated over each value with your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

### sum of two arrays

```
$a=array(1,2,3); 
$b=array(2,3,4);
$c=array_($a+$b);
echo $c;
```

Output:

> 3 5 7